# Make appium search faster

Tags: java, android, appium, pageobjects

Consider the following code 
the getCurrentPage looks like

```
public PageObject getCurrentPage() {
    List<PageObject> pageObjects = getAllPages();
    for (PageObject pageObject : pageObjects) {
        if (((CommsPageBase) pageObject).isCurrentlyVisible()) {
            return pageObject;
        }
    }
    throw new NotFoundException();
}
```

And each page has a different element to be searched

```
public boolean isCurrentlyVisible() {
            return this.elementOperator.isAttached(<elementToBeSearched>);
    }
```

The `isCurrentlyVisible()` is slower as in checks for at least 4 times(around 2-3 sec) and worst case of knowing the current page becomes much slower. How can I make it faster?